# Send a list of selected items in Knockout on form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Say we use Knockout and have an `observableArray`, that we load into a simple html table. Every item in this array, has a checkbox.

In the bottom of the table, we have a form and a button. On the form post, we want to send the ID's of all the selected items to the server.

How do I solve this problem, so I avoid a nitty gritty solution?

**My thoughts:**

Option #1:

You could make a field in the Knockout viewmodel, that is called "OrderList", that iterates all the items in the array, and build up a comma-separated list, that is shown as a hidden field, we post to the server.

Option #2:

Every time an item is checked, we call a method on the controller, that stores it server side.

**Conclusion on my thoughts**:

I don't find either solution elegant. First one is a bit nitty gritty, and the second one requires a lot of server side communication.

How would you normally solve this, in an efficient and clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinon, the whole point of using binding (with `knockout` here) is to have a structure that we can send to the server at all time, without additional code to grab the data from the interface.

If you can't do that, I think the viewmodel and binding need some update.

I must say I do not use form post with `knockout`, I rather use ajax calls and do not post the page/form.

With ajax calls, for example using `jQuery` , it is pretty easy to send your viewmodel as a `JSON` object:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/...',
         data: ko.toJSON(yourModel),
         //other stuff
})
```

With form post I guess you can maintain a hidden field with a `value` binding containing your viewmodel, if necessary (if the elements you need are not already in the form).

### Back to your question

Why don't you just send the whole observableArray as it is, and parse the data server side to look for selected items only?

If you prefer to send data as a comma-separated list, you can using a computed observable like this:

```
var orderList = ko.computed(function () {
    var arr = myObservableArray();
    var ol = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i].isChecked) ol += (ol.length > 0 ? ";" : "") + arr[i].Id;
    return ol;
}
```

And in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: orderList" id="myOrderList" />
```

Every time your `observableArray` is updated, the computed observable is updated.

You can read more about computed observables **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show multiple solutions. Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have an observable array in the viewmodel, say "orderList", that is supposed to contain the ids of the selected items. I define a function in the viewmodel "fillOrderList". I'll bind all the checkboxes "checked" event to this same function "fillOrderList". What this function does is either push or remove [through: `this.orderList.push()` / `this.orderList.remove()`] the related row id in "orderList" [given of course that you can access the id of each row and use it in the "fillOrderList" function].

This way, when the button is clicked, you basically would not have to iterate or do anything at all, as the ids of the selected items will be already available in the observable array "orderList" - you can pass that to the server and that's it.

I hope this helps.